# Cant create an object inside main

Tags: c#, abstract

I have an abstract class which name is `abclass`,

why i cant create an object like

```
abclass ab1 = new abclass();
```

from `main`

I have  constructor in `abclass` also.

Comment: This may be helpful to you, as far as a work-around. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515876/c-creating-an-instance-of-an-abstract-class-without-defining-new-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an `abstract class`.

If you don't provide an implementation for some methods on your `abstract class`, it cannot, obviously, work.

I suggest you Google 'abstract classes' for more information.

If you want to instantiate your `class`, remove the `abstract` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Read about `"Abstract Classes"` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

It is beautifully explained !!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: Abstract class can not be instantiated .

Lets do some basics here:

check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx

Comment: i will read thank you very much